# Issue with windowing and trigger in beamSql

Tags: apache-beam

How to use GlobalWindow and Repeated.forever(...) trigger together ?

What my understanding is , it should be written something like :

```
PCollection<BeamRecord> record100 = record3.apply(Window.<BeamRecord>into(
  FixedWindows.of(org.joda.time.Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()))
    .withAllowedLateness(org.joda.time.Duration.standardMinutes(1))
    .discardingFiredPanes());
```

But I don't know how to implement GlobalWindow with this trigger.

**Note :** In record3 group operation has been applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i implemented trigger for a bounded data source and worked perfectly.

```
PCollection<BeamRecord> record30_trig = record30.apply(Window.<BeamRecord>into(
  new GlobalWindows())
    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()))
    .withAllowedLateness(org.joda.time.Duration.standardMinutes(1))
    .discardingFiredPanes());
```